# Mac OS X: How to upgrade Mail.app without upgrading Mac OS X

Tags: macos, email

I'm using Mail.app version 5.3 with Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion).

How can I upgrade Mail.app version without purchasing the Mac OS X 10.8? (is it possible?).

Thanks :)

Comment: voting to migrate to [su], as this isn't a programming question

Comment: How can I migrate this question to Super User?